# php+mysqlupdate

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql table data
where primary key is (id,seq)

```
id  name  seq
------------
1    a     1
1    b     2
1    c     3
1    d     4
```

Now what i  have to do is delete the 1st row and reduce the values of seq in remaining rows by 1

I am using php PDO. And i have deleted the first row and then  fetched the remaining  rows in $result and then did following

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))

 $dbh->exec("update tablename set seq = seq-1 where id  = $row1['id'] and seq > 1 ");
```

I am getting following error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry  for key 'PRIMARY'

could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are your rows in `$result` sorted by `seq`?

Comment: I just did select * from .... and put it in result

Comment: try this with `select * from tablename order by seq asc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem right, but if this while statement:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Loops through rows "b", "c" and "d", the problem is that, with the first loop, the values of "seq" for b, c and d are 1, 2, 3, and then in the second loop, the values of sec for b, c, and d would be 1, 1 and to. Maybe it's the problem.
I think what you should do is:
1) Delete the first row
2) Execute the query just once

```
$dbh->exec("update tablename set seq = seq-1 where id  = $row1['id'] and seq > 1 ");
```

You could take the id from the deleted row. Besides, just to make sure everything works, you should add an order by statement to your query:

```
$dbh->exec("UPDATE tablename SET seq = seq-1 WHERE id = $row1['id'] AND seq > 1 ORDER BY seq ASC ");
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

because you set **primary key (id,seq)** together. and basic property of primary key is that..it would be unique and not NULL. so uniqueness of the combination of id and seq must be violated thats why u r getting below error.

**[REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)**